# Android обращение к ресурсам из адаптера

Tags: java, android

Здравстуйте, уважаемые кодеры и программисты имеется следующий адаптер для ViewPager и Tablayout, и значения заголовков берутся из массива, но т.к. моё приложение поддерживает много языков я хочу задать элементы массива через String ресурсы, однако через адаптер обратиться к ним не получается, подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать? Зараннее спасибо!

```
 public class TabsPagerFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private String[] tabs;

        public TabsPagerFragmentAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            tabs = new String[] {
                    "Старт",
                    "Начало работы",
                    "Подключение"
            };
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return Fragment1.getInstance();
                case 1:
                    return Fragment2.getInstance();
                case 2:
                    return Fragment3.getInstance();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return tabs[position];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return tabs.length;
        }
    }
```

Comment: описать все в ресурсах в зависимости от локали, а в массиве хранить сгененрированные id, и просто вытаскивать строки по Id-шникам

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно задействовать в адаптере контекст.

Как вариант:

```
public class TabsPagerFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private String[] tabs;
    private Context context

    public TabsPagerFragmentAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, @NonNull Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
        tabs = new String[] {
            "Старт",
            "Начало работы",
            "Подключение"
        };
}
. . .
```

Когда у Вас в адаптере будет контекст Вы сможете обращаться к ресурсам приложения, включая строковые.

```
context.getString(R.string.my_string);
```

Этим Вы решите одну часть Вашей задачи.

Для того чтобы решить вторую часть, Вам нужно создать дополнительные файлы `strings.xml` по одному для каждого языка и поместить в них соответствующие переводы строк. Подробно об этом можно почитать в [статье](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/locale.php).

Comment: Файлы уже реализованы, большое спасибо за подробный ответ!)

Comment: Такие вещи удобнее хранить в arrays